Sticky left column, with columns on right being on top of the first when swiped on mobile
I want to optimize my table for mobile, where the first column is sticky/frozen with a fixed width of 50%. But when you swipe, the columns on the right should not go below the sticky first column, instead, go on top of the column with the "frozen/sticky" positioning, so that the user can compare the packages on the right efficiently.
Here is my current code:


.service-category {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #e8e8e8 !important;
}

.check {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f9f9f9 !important;
}

table thead th:first-child {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  /* Match the background with header */
}


/* Ensure the first cell in each row is sticky too */

tbody td:first-child {
  /* position: sticky; */
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  /* Match the background with header */
  z-index: 0;
}


/* Ensure proper scrolling behavior on mobile */

.div1 {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.uk-table {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 400px;
  /* Set a minimum width to ensure the table is scrollable */
}

table tr td:first-child {
  /* Default color for the first cell in every row */
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  /* light gray */
}


/* Targeting the first cell in every even row */

table tr:nth-child(even) td:first-child {
  background-color: white;
  /* darker gray */
}
<div class="uk-overflow-auto div1" style="overflow-x: auto;">
  <table class="uk-table uk-table-striped uk-table-small">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 40%;"><span class="uk-h4">Services</span></th>
        <th><span class="uk-h4">Apostille</span></th>
        <th><span class="uk-h4">Easy</span></th>
        <th><span class="uk-h4">Full</span></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="service-category"><span class="uk-h6 uk-font-secondary uk-text-bold">BEFORE WEDDING</span></td>
        <td class="service-category"></td>
        <td class="service-category"></td>
        <td class="service-category"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Wedding consultation</td>
        <td>15min</td>
        <td>Unlimited</td>
        <td>Unlimited</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Passports translations</td>
        <td class="check">&#10003;</td>
        <td class="check">&#10003;</td>
        <td class="check">&#10003;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Wedding Paperwork</td>
        <td class="check">&#10003;</td>
        <td class="check">&#10003;</td>
        <td class="check">&#10003;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Power of attorney</td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="check">&#10003;</td>
        <td class="check">&#10003;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Wedding planning support</td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="check">&#10003;</td>
        <td class="check">&#10003;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Prenuptial agreement</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="check">&#10003;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Airport pickup</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="check">&#10003;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="service-category"><span class="uk-h6 uk-font-secondary uk-text-bold">Wedding day</span></td>
        <td class="service-category"></td>
        <td class="service-category"></td>
        <td class="service-category"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Civil Wedding Booking</td>
        <td class="check">&#10003;</td>
        <td class="check">&#10003;</td>
        <td class="check">&#10003;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Witnesses</td>
        <td class="check">&#10003;</td>
        <td class="check">&#10003;</td>
        <td class="check">&#10003;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Documents translation</td>
        <td class="check">&#10003;</td>
        <td class="check">&#10003;</td>
        <td class="check">&#10003;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Certificate</td>
        <td>1 apostille</td>
        <td>1 apostille + 1 GCC</td>
        <td>Apostile + GCC + 1 Extra embassy</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Transport to Public Service Hall</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="check">&#10003;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="service-category"><span class="uk-h6 uk-font-secondary uk-text-bold">After wedding</span></td>
        <td class="service-category"></td>
        <td class="service-category"></td>
        <td class="service-category"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Documents Shipping</td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="check">&#10003;</td>
        <td class="check">&#10003;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ministry of Foreign Affairs</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Upon validation</td>
        <td>UAE</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Married Or Refunded</td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="check">&#10003;</td>
        <td class="check">&#10003;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>After Wedding Support</td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="check">&#10003;</td>
        <td class="check">&#10003;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Airport drop off</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="check">&#10003;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="service-category"><span class="uk-h6 uk-font-secondary uk-text-bold">Extra</span></td>
        <td class="service-category"></td>
        <td class="service-category"></td>
        <td class="service-category"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Extra services</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>On demand</td>
        <td>On demand</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>




Hey there, welcome to StackOverflow! Just a quick heads out that this is not a place where you can just ask people to give you the code for something you desire, rather you should ask questions about the problems you're having while implementing the feature(s) yourself.
